# Draw rounded corners on radial menu edges

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-drawable

I've been using [Radial Menu Widget](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/radial-menu-widget/) in my application. [Here](http://pastebin.com/eY0kGvvJ) is the code for radial menu widget view (Its kinda lengthy). I need corner edges on top of each pie slice. How can I achieve this? I failed to understand the code as I'm new to `Canvas` and `Paint`. Kindly guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try setting a background instead, with the shape described in your drawable dir, something liek this

```
  <layer-list>
  <item >
     <shape>
            <corners android:radius="50dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ccffffff" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <padding android:bottom="3dip" 
                     android:left="3dip"
                     android:right="3dip"
                     android:top="3dip" />
     </shape>
   </item>
 </layer-list>
```